# Is it possible to push a payload at time of subscription registration using HotChocolate?

Tags: graphql, graphql-subscriptions, hotchocolate

Using hotchocolate graphql server 10.3.5 w/ pure-code-first.  Clients currently query and subscribe to receive changes, works fine.

However, the query schema and subscription payload schema are often identical.  I'd prefer that clients need only do the subscribe alone -- they'd get an immediate 'push' and updates as before.

Presumably hooking into a hotchocolate 'user subscribed' event and doing a push there would be the solution if it's not already supported.  But unsure where/how to approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per hotchocolate author in V10.4 and V11.0 this will be straightforward, closing pending final release of those versions.

Comment: After a discussion on hotchocolate's slack it seems this is not possible yet (V12).